# CRUD using observables without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement CRUD in angular using observables without subscribing them in `ts` file but using `async` in `html`.

My goal is to get, add, edit and delete items fetched from server without refreshing the page after every request.

I tried to do this with `BehaviorSubject`, `ReplaySubject`, `AsyncSubject` and also look for materials however I didn't find anything useful.

Could someone give an example how to implement this kind of crud with best possible pattern?

Below I paste my code cleaned from my previous attempts and data structures returned from API.

Thanks in advance.

in `documents.service.ts`

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DocumentsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDocuments(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`https://localhost:5001/docs`)
  }

  postDocument(item: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any[]>(`https://localhost:5001/docs`, item)
  }

  putDocument(id: number, item: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put<any[]>(`https://localhost:5001/docs/${id}`, item)
  }

  deleteDocument(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete<any>(`https://localhost:5001/docs/${id}`)
  }
}
```

in `documents.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DocumentsService } from 'src/app/services/documents.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  documents$: Observable<any> = new Observable()

  constructor(private documentsService: DocumentsService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDocuments();
  }

  getDocuments(): void {
    this.documents$ = this.documentsService.getDocuments()
  }

  postDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.postDocument({
      "title": "title",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2765111/pexels-photo-2765111.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
      "madeBy": {
        "userName": "mike mock",
        "email": "mike@mock.com"
      }
    })
  }

  putDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.putDocument(4, {
      "title": "title",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2765111/pexels-photo-2765111.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
      "madeBy": {
        "userName": "mike mock",
        "email": "mike@mock.com"
      }
    })
  }

  deleteDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.deleteDocument(5)
  }
}
```

in `documents.component.html`

```html
<p routerLink="/">home works!</p>

<button (click)="postDocument()">add me</button>
<button (click)="putDocument()">edit me</button>
<button (click)="deleteDocument()">delete me</button>


<p *ngFor="let document of documents$ | async">
    {{ document | json }}
</p>
```

HTTP GET Respone:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 47,
    "title": "docker",
    "description": "lorem ipsum",
    "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3464632/pexels-photo-3464632.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "madeBy": {
      "username": "mike mock",
      "email": "mike@mock.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "title": "linux",
    "description": "second description",
    "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3900437/pexels-photo-3900437.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
    "madeBy": {
      "username": "mike mock",
      "email": "mike@mock.com"
    }
  }
]
```

HTTP POST/PUT/DELETE Response:

```json
{
  "id": 50,
  "title": "some text",
  "description": "lorem ipsum",
  "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2765111/pexels-photo-2765111.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
  "madeBy": {
    "username": "mike mock",
    "email": "mike@mock.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: This might look a little bit over the top for you, but I recommend to include a store. Each CRUD operation is an action you can dispatch on click. The requests are sent by effects and your component selects only the documents from store.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm, I do not believe it is appropriate to suggest a state management option to a novice who is building a simple CRUD application.

Answer (score 0):

Observables are lazy and won't execute until they are subscribed to.

Update your component to:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { DocumentsService } from 'src/app/services/documents.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  documents$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

  constructor(private documentsService: DocumentsService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDocuments();
  }

  getDocuments(): void {
    this.documentsService.getDocuments().subscribe(this.documents$);
  }

  postDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.postDocument({
      "title": "title",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2765111/pexels-photo-2765111.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
      "madeBy": {
        "userName": "mike mock",
        "email": "mike@mock.com"
      }
    }).subscribe(_ => this.getDocuments());
  }

  putDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.putDocument(4, {
      "title": "title",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "imageUrl": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2765111/pexels-photo-2765111.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
      "madeBy": {
        "userName": "mike mock",
        "email": "mike@mock.com"
      }
    }).subscribe(_ => this.getDocuments());
  }

  deleteDocument(): void {
    this.documentsService.deleteDocument(5).subscribe(_ => this.getDocuments());
  }
}
```

I would also strongly recommend you strongly type your api and remove the uses of `any`.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I usually use strong types however for this question I changed type to `any` to not complicate this question.

Comment: async pipe does the subscription for you. That's the whole point of using async pipe. Please update your answer that is just simply false

Comment: I realized after the fact I didn't address the part of your question about getting the updated data. You could call this.getDocuments() from within your other methods. I'll update my answer to show.

Comment: @Jean-XavierRaynaud, please see the author's original postDocument, putDocument and deleteDocument methods. The async pipe in the author's question only executes the read portion of their CRUD application.

Comment: @mikolajs, it may also make sense to use the pipe finalize for this use case as well, if you wanted to refresh the data even on error.

Comment: @JohnD I agree that the original code doesn't do any kind of update of the data, but that's not because the Observable isn't subscribed, it's because the Observable here is the http call, not an Observable with the data. Subscribing to it won't change a thing because a) the async pipe subscribes, b) you're subscribing to an http call which is an Observable that emits a "close" event automatically when the server responds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your service. In your service your getDocuments() is simply making a call to your backend. When in your component you're writing this.documents$ = this.documentsService.getDocuments() it will call the function once, read the data and never update it later.

So instead you need to create a subject to store the data in your service, make it available externally with an .asObservable(), link your component to that observable and update the content of the subject after each http call.

Something like this:

```
export class DocumentsService {
  private _documents$ = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Document>>([]);
  public documents$: Observable<Array<Document>>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.documents$ = this._documents$.asObservable()
  }

  getDocuments(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.http.get<any[]>(`https://localhost:5001/docs`).switchmap(
      (response) => this._documents$.next(response)
    )
  }

  postDocument(item: any): Observable<any> {
    # update _documents$ here
  }

  putDocument(id: number, item: any): Observable<any> {
    # update _documents$ here
  }

  deleteDocument(id: number): Observable<any> {
    # update _documents$ here
  }
}
```

Then in your component simply update the line where you define the documents

```
this.documents$ = this.documentsService.documents$
```

And it should work.

Comment: The author's postDocument, putDocument and deleteDocument methods will not invoke the service methods without subscribing. Please update your answer with the updated component portions.

Comment: @JohnD they are basically trivial to do, simply read the response from the server and update the behaviour subject in a switchman or exhaust map.

Comment: `postDocument(item: any): Observable<any>` will not execute in the author's current consuming component because it returns an Observable<any> and will require subscription. `postDocument(): void` in the component will need to be updated as well.